# How to use React Routes with esbuild?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-live-server, esbuild

I'm using esbuild to create React app, its working good, but, when I tried to enable react-router on the app, it can be builder and works, but I'm not able to move between routes, the initial config:

```
(async () => {
const builder = await build({
    bundle: true,
    define: {"process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev')},
    entryPoints: ["app/index.tsx"],
    incremental: true,
    minify: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod',
    
    outfile: './app/public/main.js',
    loader: {
        '.svg': 'dataurl',
        '.png': 'dataurl'
    },
    
});

chokidar.watch("app/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}", {
    interval: 0
}).on("all", () => {
    builder.rebuild()
});

liveServer.start({
    open: true,
    port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
    root: './app/public'
}) })();
```

And my routes are declare:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path={'/'} element={<Login />} />
    <Route path={'register'} element={<Register />} />
</Routes>
```

but the server gives me: `Cannot GET /register`

Answer (score 1):

Hello you could try this;

```js
import esbuild from "esbuild";
import http from "node:http";

const ctx = await esbuild.context({
   bundle: true,
   define: {"process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev')},
   entryPoints: ["app/index.tsx"],
   incremental: true,
   minify: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod',
   outfile: './app/public/main.js',
   loader: {
       '.svg': 'dataurl',
       '.png': 'dataurl'
   },
});


let { host, port } = await ctx.serve({
  port: 3000,
  servedir: "./app/public",
});


http
  .createServer((clientReq, clientRes) => {
    const options = {
      hostname: host,
      port: port,
      path: clientReq.url,
      method: clientReq.method,
      headers: clientReq.headers,
    };

    const proxy = http.request(options, (res) => {
      if (res.statusCode === 404) {
        const redirectReq = http.request(
          { ...options, path: "/" },
          (proxyRes) => {
            clientRes.writeHead(proxyRes.statusCode, proxyRes.headers);
            proxyRes.pipe(clientRes, { end: true });
          }
        );

        redirectReq.end();
      } else {
        clientRes.writeHead(res.statusCode, res.headers);
        res.pipe(clientRes, { end: true });
      }
    });

    clientReq.pipe(proxy, { end: true });
  })
  .listen(1274);
```

and visit http://localhost:1274.

This works by using the inbuilt Node HTTP server to intercept client requests with status code 404. We assume these are react-router page requests and send them to / where React is.

You could do the same using Caddy or nginx, I reckon and perhaps the latest versions of `esbuild` have a better way of doing this nowadays, or the API changed.

I used:

- node v18.15.0
- esbuild@0.18.12

I hate JavaScript.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

create new folder 'components' => create new file navigation

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <nav className='flex justify-between items-center h-[50px] px-5 shadow-md bg-gray-500 text-white'>
                <h3>Git search</h3>

                <span>
                    <Link to='/' className='mr-2'>Home</Link>
                    <Link to='/favourites'>Favourites</Link>
                </span>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}
export default Navigation
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Comment: This doesn't work for getting react routes working specifically with esBuild